# Value of $V/(250\pi)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

A cylindrical container is to be made from certain solid material with the following constraints:

- It has fixed inner volume $V$ mm${}^3$ ,has a $2$ mm thick solid wall and is open at the top.
- The bottom of the container is a solid circular disc of thickness $2$ mm and is of radius equal to the outer radius of the container.

If the volume of the material used to make the container is minimum when the inner radius of the container is $10$ mm, then find the value of $\frac{V}{250\pi}$.

**My Attempt** The total volume is volume of solid wall and the solid circular disk. So we have Volume of material $ =\pi.h((r+2)^2-r^2)+\pi.r^2.2$  so as volume is minimized at $10$, I differentiated the expression put value of $r$ to get value of $h=-12$ which is impossible. I think I have misinterpreted the question. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting up a little bit. Can you check to make sure I haven't changed the meaning?

Comment: You forgot that inner volume is $V$: use that to express $h$ as a function of $r$.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting .everything is correct:)

Comment: Can you specify more how does it help

Comment: As you wrote it, volume of material is a function of TWO variables ($r$ and $h$). But there is a constraint (inner volume fixed) so either you employ Lagrange multipliers or express $h$ as a function of $r$ and substitute this expression into the function to minimize.

Answer (score -2):

$V = \pi r^2 h\\
M = \pi ( (r+2)^2 - r^2) h + \pi (r+2)^2$

$\frac{dM}{dr}  = \pi [4h + (4r+4)\frac {dh}{dr} + 2r+4] = 0\\
\frac{dV}{dr}  = \pi [2r h + r^2 \frac {dh}{dr}] = 0\\
\frac {dh}{dr} = \frac {-2h}{r}\\
2h + (2r+2)\frac {-2h}{r} + r + 2= 0\\
(r+2) = (2h - \frac {4h}{r})\\
r(r+2) = 2h (r-4)\\ 
h = \frac {r(r+2)}{2(r-4)}$

$r = 10\\
h = \frac {120}{12} = 10\\
V = 1000\pi\\
\frac V{250\pi} = 4$

Comment: I didn't get you at the step $dm/dr$ and also in last value of M I think you have missed a two

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Carefully step through the product rule for derivatives, and expand out the brackets in $(r+2)^2-r^2$